# Specific text in a string

Tags: json, string, split

I know there are at least hundreds of examples out there, but I just can't find the one that works best for me.
I have a string that is displayed like this (with all the spaces, the backslashes, etc):

```
string textInfo = "{\n    \"code\": null,\n    \"success\": true,\n    \"data\": [\n        {\n            \"id\": 109322,\n            \"name\": \"Name Surname\",\n            \"display_name\": \"Name SURNAME\",\n            \"city\": \"Bellair\\u00eb\",\n            \"zip\": \"24000\",\n            \"street\": \"boulevard 21\"\n        }\n    ],\n    \"message\": null,\n    \"total\": 1\n}"
```

i would like to extract for example only the id, or name or message on another string. For example:

```
string resultID = "109322" //for my id
string resultName = "Name Surname" //for my name
```

etc...

Thank you very much for your time and effort in helping me.

Kind Regards

Comment: This looks like json. If so, find a JSON parser example for your language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel so bad not trying harder. Anyway here is my working code for Windows Application C#

```
string jsonString = "{\n    \"code\": null,\n    \"success\": true,\n    \"data\": [\n        {\n            \"id\": 109322,\n            \"name\": \"Name Surname\",\n            \"display_name\": \"Name SURNAME\",\n            \"city\": \"Bellair\\u00eb\",\n            \"zip\": \"24000\",\n            \"street\": \"boulevard 21\"\n        }\n    ],\n    \"message\": null,\n    \"total\": 1\n}"

JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

return (string)jsonObj["data"][0]["id"];
```

And output is: 109322

Answer (score 1):

What language are you tring to use?

As your string is in JSON format, try parsing it with a JSON parser and then reading from the object

Comment: Jon, thank you for your quick response, could you send me an example

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Jon, omg sry, i didn't stated the most important thing. Its a C# Desktop Application, making a HttpWebRequest, and receiving HttpWebResponse with application/json contentType. thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Jon, this string is in JSON (Javascript Object Notation) format.

Each language has a method to convert from JSON into an object from which you can extract each attribute as a property. In javascript you can use `JSON.stringify(textInfo)` to represent the data in an object form.

The mechanics would look like the following:

```
jsonString = "{\n    \"code\": null,\n    \"success\": true,\n    \"data\": [\n        {\n            \"id\": 109322,\n            \"name\": \"Name Surname\",\n            \"display_name\": \"Name SURNAME\",\n            \"city\": \"Bellair\\u00eb\",\n            \"zip\": \"24000\",\n            \"street\": \"boulevard 21\"\n        }\n    ],\n    \"message\": null,\n    \"total\": 1\n}"
dataObject = JSON.parse(jsonString)

var resultID = dataObject.data.id //for my id
var resultName = dataObject.data.name //for my name
```

the rest of the properties can be similarly queried.

For reference, here is a "prettified" version of your JSON data:

```
{  
   "code":null,
   "success":true,
   "data":[  
      {  
         "id":109322,
         "name":"Name Surname",
         "display_name":"Name SURNAME",
         "city":"Bellairë",
         "zip":"24000",
         "street":"boulevard 21"
      }
   ],
   "message":null,
   "total":1
}
```

Comment: Yes Ulad Kasach, Jon was right, i was about to test it. Your example works great. thank you for your help